# Obtaining the constant from the cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, random-variable

Let the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$ has been given as follows:

$F(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<0 \\ 
\frac{x^2}{10} & \text{ if } 0<x<1\\ 
\frac{x+2}{8} & \text{ if } 1\leq x\leq2 \\ 
\frac{c(6x-x^2-1)}{2} & \text{ if } 2\leq x\leq3 \\ 
1 & \text{ if } x>3 
\end{cases}$

The constant $c$ could be easily evaluated if the given distribution function belongs to continuous distribution. This function has discontinuity at points $1$. For checking the discontinuity at points $3$ and $2$, we would need $c$.

Can I take the derivative of this distribution function and obtain $c$ using the total probability theorem of probability density function?.

**EDIT.1**

If I use the usual differentiation method, the answer after integrating the probability density will turn out to be $c=\frac{31}{20}$.

Comment: The "total probability theorem" amounts to asserting that the limiting value of $F(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ is $1$.  Since this limit does not depend on $c$, how do you hope that will help you?

Comment: @whuber That would have helped me if I knew that the distribution function is continuous at $3$. So, the limiting value at three would have been $1$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The limiting value is explicitly $1$, because $F(x)=1$ for all $x\gt 3$.  Continuity is irrelevant.  I note you have not been careful with inequalities, because your definition of $F$ is contradictory: it has $F(1)=1^2/10$ and $F(1)=(1+2)/8 \ne 1/10$.  Therefore there is no unique solution for $c$ and, regardless, $F$ is never a continuous distribution for any $c$.

Comment: Thanks, So what I calculated is not correct $\frac{31}{20}$. I am really confused in the terminology that you just used. I am not getting the point. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: I cannot identify any technical term I used that doesn't already appear in your question.  But note that when $c=31/20$, your formula gives $$F(3)=c(6(3)-3^2-1)/2 = 31/5$$ which is impossible. Plug in any value $c\in[1/7,1/4]$ and see what happens to the graph of $F$.